# Stop loading images from cache (GridView containing android volley images )

Tags: android, caching, gridview, android-volley

I have a gridView containing only images that are loaded dynamically from a server using Volley library. 
Layout File:

```
<GridView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  
</GridView>
```

So i'am loading all the images from the server using an adapter that downloads the images with Volley:

```
   public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Album>{
String urlImage;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Activity activity, List<Album> items) {
    super(activity, R.layout.custum_grid_view_item, items);
}

    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
    Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custum_grid_view_item, null);
    Album item = getItem(position);


    final ImageView  myImageOfItemList = (ImageView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.image_grid_view);

        urlImage =item.getImage();

    myImageOfItemList.setTag(urlImage);


    imageLoader.get(urlImage, new ImageListener() {

           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   myImageOfItemList.setImageDrawable(getContext()
                              .getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home));
            Log.e("ImageLoadError", "Image Load Error: " + error.getMessage());
           }

           @Override
           public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
            if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
             // load image into imageview
                myImageOfItemList.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
            }
           }
          });
    return rowView;
}

  }
```

The problem is just after the Android app user accesses the gridView, if an image is updated in the server the old image is always stored in the cache so the user never get the updated version after the first time he accessed the gridView items

I tried clearing, deleting and denying the cache with:

```
AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url);
AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().invalidate(url, true);
MemoryCacheUtil.removeFromCache(imageUri, imageLoader.getMemoryCache());
```

But it's always the same even though i always reload the data in "onResume" of my activity.
So if an image is added or deleted it works fine, but when i change it's always the old one that is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Volley caches images on disk is according to the HTTP cache headers. If the cache headers say the image is still valid, then it will not be requested again from the server.

The correct way to handle images IMO is by this logic:
When updating an image on the server, treat it as if it is not an update but an addition. Give the image a different name, like adding a time stamp to the name, to allow the app to "know" it needs to retrieve it from the server.

The cache is working for you in allowing a smoother experience by loading images faster. You want to use it when you can and only go out to the network when really necessary.

Consider this scenario:

1. User opens app.
2. Grid cube no.1 needs to load example.com/image_20140614.jpg.
3. Volley checks the cache, image is not present, so a network request is performed and the image is cached.
4. After X amount of time user opens the app again.
5. Grid cube no.1 needs to load example.com/image_20140614.jpg.
6. Volley checks the cache and loads image from disk - quickly.
7. After X amount of time user opens the app again.
8. Grid cube no.1 needs to load example.com/image_20140622.jpg. You consider this an update, but in practical terms it is a new image (notice the time stamp).
9. Volley checks cache, image is not present, so a network request is performed and the image is cached.

If you control the server, that is the way to go.
If you do not however, you need to change the caching strategy for Volley to check if any changes have occurred to to the image.

Comment: Well i did that by adding the image and changing the name and it works fine  but what is the best practice in my case delete the cache or change the name after each update (which mean another request to the database to delete then add another image name) ?

Comment: Don't think about managing the cache. Volley takes care of it. Make your memory cache as big as you deem fit, and the default size of the disk cache is 5MB which is very reasonable.